# What is the minimum non-integer dimension for which the XY model shows a phase transition? (if well-defined)

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I know that [XY statistical model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_XY_model) for $d=2$ doesn't show a regular phase transition , while the $3d$ has, I was wondering what is the behaviour for $2< d < 3$.

If it is simpler one could consider another model in its class of universality, like it's done for the $2+\epsilon$ expansion.

The simplest hypothesis is that exist a $d_{min}$ between 2 and 3 such that for values of dimension greater than $d_{min}$ there is phase transition.

Assuming this number has a meaning for every statistical model, I would like to ask if it is universal with respect to the simmetries of the order parameter.

Going further, what is the behaviour of the critical temperature around $d_{min}$, is that universal?

Comment: Depending how you set up your model in fractional dimensions, there will be long-range order as soon as $d>2$. The existence of long-range order is closely related to the transience of the random walk on the underlying graph. See [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02186284) for one direction and [this one](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v60/i2/p1500_1) for the other direction. Note that it is not clear how to make the latter paper rigorous, but it should be convincing for a theoretical physicist.

Comment: I've quickly looked at the interesting articles you linked, that could be considered the answer to my question, the value $d_{min}=2$ is "universal" with respect to O(n) hamiltonians (so automatically XY model), but it appears that the situation is still not clear for $n=1$, it would be also interesting to know the behaviour of the critical temperature, but I think it's a difficult problem.

Comment: Of course, this universal behavior does not extend to $O(1)$: this is just the Ising model, which has a phase transition in dimension $2$ (and should have one for any dimension $d>1$, if you set up the model correctly). The difference is due to the fact that the symmetry of the latter is discrete, while it is continuous for $O(N)$ with $N\geq 2$.

Comment: Ok, in fact I was about to ask for the Ising model but I felt that this was the result because one can say that there is phase transition in 1d at zero temperature, so I expect that kind of result, for the XY model I thought the situation was messier.